# How do I install the salesforce1 app on my iPad simulator

Tags: ios, salesforce, appium-ios

I'm trying to automate some functionalities of the salesfocre1 app, using Appium.

1. I have the application on my iPad (real device), but don't know how to connect it with my appium code.
2. I have the iPad simulator on my Mac but I'm not able to find any installer package files of the Salesforce1 app, to install it on the simulator.
3. I am not the developer of the above application, so I do not have access to the source code and bundle id, to run it on my XCODE and get it on the simulator.

I've previously done automation on Android using real devices/emulators but it was an easy case where we downloaded the app from play store and were able to test it on the emulator/real device, just wondering how to do the same on iOS. Please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It simply does not work that easy for iOS.
Since you want to run your Appium tests on real device, you need to build application (.IPA file) from source code or resign the one you have with your Apple developer account.
Then you need to build WebDriverAgent with same provision profile - so that Appium can interact with your application. Only with steps I described it will work.

So in your case:
1. No way to get source code - ask smb to provide developer build, release one in any case may not work with Appium.
2. No need to search - you won't find any installer.
3. No way to get Apple developer account - you have to use 3rd party cloud like saucelabs or browserstack, they will resign IPA file with theirs profiles and you will be able to run tests in cloud